# Wordpress collapsing menu keeps not expanded

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu

Currently i'm working on this site: [goo.gl/NUD31R](http://goo.gl/NUD31R)

The problem is the submenu keeps not expanded after clicking on links.

This the code which is, of course, placed in the header.php

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.menu .dropdown a').click(function(e){  
          if ($(this).parent().children('.sub-menu').is(':visible')) {
               $(this).parent().children('.sub-menu').toggle();
          } else {
               $(this).parent().children('.sub-menu').toggle();
          }
     });
});
</script>
```

I guess it's just a small thing and i really appreciate your help! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sub menu to expand after clicking and after the page changes you need to toggle it on doc.ready instead of on click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li.current-menu-item").closest(".sub-menu").toggle();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your fast reply, but i don't get it working like this.